# Why so big difference in GC time in two implementations

Tags: garbage-collection, erlang, tail-recursion

have two algorithm implementations:

```
average(List) -> sum(List) / len(List).

sum([]) -> 0;
sum([Head | Tail]) -> Head + sum(Tail).

len([]) -> 0;
len([_ | Tail]) -> 1 + len(Tail).



average1(List) -> average_acc(List, 0,0).

average_acc([], Sum, Length) -> Sum / Length;
average_acc([H | T], Sum, Length) -> average_acc(T, Sum + H, Length + 1).
```

and output for trace GC events gc_start gc_end (gc started and stopped):

here every next value for process is a sum of preceding value and last gc time

> average: 5189
> average: 14480
> average: 15118
>
> average1: 594

Why so big difference?

PS. I use wall clock time.

Comment: May be its partially because of usage of two tail-recursive function in first case, but so big impact?

Comment: Isn't "tail-recursion" what I see among the tags?

Comment: Could you please rephrase: "here every next value for process is a sum of preceding value and last gc time"

Comment: Roberto Aloi: 15118 = 14480 + gc_time3, 14480 = 5189 + gc_time2, 5189 = gc_time1

Comment: Roberto Aloi: You mean that first implementation isnt really tail recursion?

Comment: @Yola: No it definitely is not. Which function is called last? It is `erlang:'+'/2`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should not use wall clock time (`timestamp` flag) to measure what GC takes because even GC is not rescheduled in Erlang scheduler thread the thread self can be rescheduled by underlying OS. So you should use `cpu_timestamp` instead.
2. Your `average/1` is using `sum/1` and `count/1` implementation where both are **not tail recursive** so you allocate `2*N` stack frames which makes big difference in performance to `average1/1` which uses tail recursive `average_acc/3`. So `average1/1` performs exactly as loop in other languages.

### Edit:

1. Edited according Yola stated he is using `timestamp` flag for trace messages.

Comment: Memory usage and the amount of time spent garbage collecting are notoriously tricky to predict.
....... 
Now, **what should you do if you want to calculate the time spent garbage collecting**, or if you want to have an accurate record of exactly when a specific trace event is generated? You should use the timestamp flag, which will add a timestamp to all messages.
"Erlang Programming" by Francesco Cesarini and Simon Thompson.

Comment: @Yola - you are right, you can include timestamp to trace message and then you really measure what GC takes, but corresponding scheduler thread can be suspended by underlying OS. You should use cpu_timestamp.

Comment: Thanks, i understand difference between cpu time and wall time. Thanks.

Comment: @Yola anyway 2. answers why you experience so different times.

Comment: In addition, the slow variant traverses the list twice. The fast variant does not.